# MAMP MySQL stop working after updating mac High Sierra 10.13.2

Tags: mamp, macos-high-sierra

I updated my mac and MAMP stopped working, or my MySQL Server wont start:

[image]

I tried to delete the ib_logfileN:s

[image]

since that allways worked for me before, but it doesn't work this time.. Any idea what might solve this?

Thanks

Comment: What is that first screenshot showing us? Do you mean you click on the Start buttons and nothing happens? Or does it give you an error?

Comment: @underscore_d The first screenshot shows that only the Apache server starts and not the MySQL Server :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall my latest version of MAMP and re-install a older version (3.5.2) worked for me.

Comment: 3.5 works. Although you might run into problems accessing certain APIs due to cURL being configured to use TLS1.0, which is now depreciated. Paypal, Stripe etc will no longer work with MAMP 3.5. it is possible to upgrade this manually with these instructions : https://github.com/lunr/mamp-curl-tls