# Why doesn't phpMyAdmin work on MAMP Pro 4.5 under MAC OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin, mamp-pro

I just upgraded to Mamp pro 4.5 and now phpMyAdmin will not run. I get the error:

> File ./vendor/autoload.php missing or not readable.  Most likely you
>   did not run Composer to install library files.

I have run composer to install and/or update. I still receive the error.

Any help or clues to a fix will be appreciated.

Comment: I too am having the same issue, I think there is an issue with v4.5 I am hoping for a fix soon.

Comment: Are the MySQL servers running at all in MAMP? Are you having this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184740/mamp-mysql-stop-working-after-updating-mac-high-sierra-10-13-2